# Editing iTunes Library in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, itunes

I want to edit the "Date Added" attribute of my music files, i thought i could do this using AppleScript, but this attribute is read only.

Then i found a file named "**iTunes Music Library.xml**", this file can be edited, but the changes will be over-written by iTunes.

It seems like i should edit the "**iTunes Library.itl**" file which is in the same folder, but how can i do this? or is there any other way  to do this?

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationale for the `Date Added` property being read-only is that it represents the date that the file was added to the iTunes Library.

The `.xml` file is only used when you want to re-import your files into iTunes, it is rewritten on pretty much any change to the library.

There's a library for understanding the format of the `.itl` file called [titl](http://code.google.com/p/titl/). I don't know if it supports the latest version of the library file format, though.

You may need to refer to the [PicardPlugins](http://code.google.com/p/picardplugins/wiki/LibraryFile) wiki for more information/ways to read/modify the library file. Changes that have happened over time are the compression of the content, and the encrypting of the data.

I would expect that you should only modify this file when iTunes is not running, though.